# Drawing 2D graphics

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, java-2d, sprite

I would like to make a simple game in Java that has already been designed. I just need a way to draw sprites, etc. It doesn't have to be anything complicated. What would be the first choice you'd recommend for this?

Comment: are we talking Swing here? I deducted so from a (erroneous) answer, but actually don't know from the question

Comment: If you are new to games I can recommend you this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsc8wGybU2IZui4lAad9F8lFjdkn2ZdWD Not much about the final product but will give you good idea how to organize the base code structure and what you can do with just default libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would heavily suggest you go with a sprite system built on top of OpenGL, like [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) or [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). Java 2D graphics drawing is too slow to be used for sprite-based games without major headaches. [I speak from bitter experience.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148478/java-2d-drawing-optimal-performance)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Java 2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

extending a JPanel is a good start:

```
    public class SpriteDrawer extends JPanel
    {
        public SpriteDrawer()
        {
            try
            {
                sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("..//images//sprite.PNG"));
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            frame = new JFrame("Sprite Drawer");
            frame.add(this);
            frame.setSize(400,400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.drawImage(0,0,400,400);
        }

        private JFrame frame;
        private Image sprite;
    }
```

this is a good example of overriding the paint method in JPanel. I hope this is what you were looking for, if not let me know and i can help you out.

Comment: no, it's not a good example: in Swing, the method to override for custom painting is paintComponent(...)

Comment: you can override paint, it works fine.

Comment: -1 for insisting on wrongness

Comment: i can program however i want and i do it that way and it works fine. I never have any problems.

Comment: yeah, sure, you are free to do whatever mistakes you insist to doing ;)

Comment: i hope that attitude gets you as far in life as you deserve to go. nowhere. =)

Comment: the expert in "little bit about C and Assembler" speaking about jave2d. You learn. End of story.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) framework useful - it's well designed for simple 2D games and includes tools for sound effects, input handling etc.