# Java Swing 2D - Draw many small stars quickly

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I'm trying to make a game, and in the game is a background that has many small stars that slowly travel from right to left.  With a full screen I may have 170 stars being drawn each frame.  The majority of the CPU time rendering each frame is in the drawing of the stars.  Is there's a way to use resources more effectively?

I have taken into consideration the points in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/200493/21618530

An approach I've used is to use device compatible VolatileImages, using 1 of 3 variants to avoid scaling with BITMASK transparency.  It takes on average 22ms to render each frame this way.

[jvisualvm profiler output for drawImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bxFa.png)

Using `fillOval()` for stars instead of drawing images reduces runtime to about 20ms each frame, with this profiler output:

[jvisualvm profiler output for fillOval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxpJl.png)

This is on a laptop with an Intel UHD 620 with a 3840x2160 monitor.  I intend for this game to be simple and playable on a wide range of graphics, so it would be good if it could run well on a device like this.

---

I'm open to other strategies to have the same outcome, but my goal here is to better understand swing 2d performance so I might improve the game overall.

MRE showing about how I've done this, on my machine the volatile image usage is slower on average that drawing the oval each time.

```
package space;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BufferCapabilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.ImageCapabilities;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.VolatileImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MRE {

    private static final int OVAL_SIZE = 4;
    private static final int NUM_STARS = 150;
    private static final boolean useImages = false;

    private static VolatileImage volatileImage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.accthreshold", "0");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RepaintManager manager = new RepaintManager() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
                // Ignored
            }

            @Override
            public Rectangle getDirtyRegion(JComponent aComponent) {
                return aComponent.getBounds();
            }

            @Override
            public void markCompletelyDirty(JComponent aComponent) {
                // Ignored
            }

            @Override
            public void markCompletelyClean(JComponent aComponent) {
                // Ignored
            }
        };
        createVolatileImage(frame);
        RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(manager);
        Timer st = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long startTime;
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                JComponent contentPanel = ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane());
                contentPanel.paintImmediately(contentPanel.getBounds());
                long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                System.out.println("Rendering time: " + elapsed / 1000000.0 + "ms.");
            }

        });

        frame.setContentPane(createContentPane());

        setWindowVisible(frame, true);
        st.start();
    }

    private static void createVolatileImage(JFrame frame) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        volatileImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(4, 4, Transparency.BITMASK);
        Graphics2D g2 = volatileImage.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    private static JPanel createContentPane() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 2500224655024127049L;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                Random rand = new Random();
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STARS; i++) {
                    double x = rand.nextDouble() * getWidth();
                    double y = rand.nextDouble() * getHeight();
                    g2.translate(x, y);
                    if(useImages) {
                        g2.drawImage(volatileImage, 0, 0, null);
                    } else {
                        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g2.fillOval(0, 0, OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
                    }
                    g2.translate(-x, -y);
                }
            }
        };
        return contentPane;
    }

    private static void setWindowVisible(JFrame frame, final boolean visible) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(visible);
            try {
                final BufferCapabilities caps = new BufferCapabilities(new ImageCapabilities(true),
                    new ImageCapabilities(true), BufferCapabilities.FlipContents.UNDEFINED);
                frame.createBufferStrategy(2, caps);
            } catch (final AWTException e) {
                frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
                System.err.println("Could not set double buffered FLIP strategy, using default double buffer: "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: When drawing with Java Swing, you have to render the entire drawing `JPanel` each and every frame.  Without seeing any code, I'd suggest creating a background image with stars one time.  You can then move the image along the X-axis and redraw it.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. We can't make suggestion is we can't see the code. Note, we don't have access to your images, so the MRE should be the example using the drawOval(...) method.

Comment: I added some code that exhibits the behavior I'm experiencing, in a rough fashion.  Drawing with a volatile image is slower than `fillOval`.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The broader issue is drawing many dynamic objects at once, such as ships or bullets.  I'm looking for strategies to achieve that quickly.

Comment: I've always created a `List` of `Bullet` objects.  The game loop using a Sewing `Timer` updates the positions of the `Bullet` objects and checks for collisions, while the drawing `JPanel` draws their positions as a filled circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a `BufferedImage` instead of a VolatileImage and the timing dropped from 40 to 4:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BufferCapabilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.ImageCapabilities;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MRE1 {

    private static final int OVAL_SIZE = 4;
    private static final int NUM_STARS = 150;
    private static final boolean useImages = true;

    private static VolatileImage volatileImage;
    private static BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.accthreshold", "0");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        createVolatileImage(frame);

        Timer st = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long startTime;
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                JComponent contentPanel = ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane());
                contentPanel.paintImmediately(contentPanel.getBounds());
                long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                System.out.println("Rendering time: " + elapsed / 1000000.0 + "ms.");
            }

        });

        frame.setContentPane(createContentPane());

        setWindowVisible(frame, true);
        st.start();
    }

    private static void createVolatileImage(JFrame frame) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        volatileImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(4, 4, Transparency.BITMASK);
        Graphics2D g2 = volatileImage.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.fillOval(0, 0, OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
        g2.dispose();

        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor( Color.WHITE );
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static JPanel createContentPane() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 2500224655024127049L;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                Random rand = new Random();

                for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STARS; i++) {
                    double x = rand.nextDouble() * getWidth();
                    double y = rand.nextDouble() * getHeight();
                    g2.translate(x, y);
                    if(useImages) {
//                        g2.drawImage(volatileImage, 0, 0, null);
                        g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
                    } else {
                        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g2.fillOval(0, 0, OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
                    }
                    g2.translate(-x, -y);
                }
            }
        };
        contentPane.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        return contentPane;
    }

    private static void setWindowVisible(JFrame frame, final boolean visible) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(visible);
            try {
                final BufferCapabilities caps = new BufferCapabilities(new ImageCapabilities(true),
                    new ImageCapabilities(true), BufferCapabilities.FlipContents.UNDEFINED);
                frame.createBufferStrategy(2, caps);
            } catch (final AWTException e) {
                frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
                System.err.println("Could not set double buffered FLIP strategy, using default double buffer: "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Also got rid of the RepaintManager since I see no need for it.

> I've used is to use device compatible VolatileImages, using 1 of 3 variants to avoid scaling with BITMASK transparency

If that means you don't want the image to scale from 4 to 6 pixels when a scaling factor of 150 is used then maybe you can use the `NoScalingIcon`. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65742492/131872

You should be able to create the Icon using your image and then paint the Icon to the BufferedImage and the image will still be 4 pixels.

Comment: That does make a big difference.  Any idea why?  I know the graphics card on this laptop doesn't have it's own memory so maybe volatile images end up somewhere worse than where the buffered images are stored.  I'll test this out on my desktop.

Comment: I've only ever used a BufferedImage. Don't know when VolatileImage with give better/worse performance.

Comment: The way I understand it is that volatile images exist on graphics card memory, not main memory (though buffered images can be accelerated in that way).  I would expect volatile to be faster.  There was another use case that drastically brought down rendering times using volatile and not buffered - but there may be thresholds of size or frequency that come in to play here.

I ran this on my desktop:  fillOval: 1.5ms, volatile: 6ms, buffered: 0.5ms.

Comment: I did some further testing, and if I switch the Transparency to TRANSLUCENT, the runtime for Volatile images is slightly faster than Buffered.

Comment: @working_man as far as I know, `VolatileImage` became obsolete for most use cases with Java 6 when Java got image acceleration for all images, most notably `BufferedImage`, smart enough to recognize whether and when updates are needed. So with `VolatileImage` there is little to gain but a lot to lose when not using it in the optimal way. So, as always, prefer the simple way (`BufferedImage`) and only try different approaches if this doesn’t work out.